# Timeout in DefaultHttpClient

Tags: java, android, timeout, httpclient

I'm a little confused on how the timeouts in DefaultHttpClient work.

I'm using this code:

```
private DefaultHttpClient createHttpClient() {
        HttpParams my_httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();

        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(my_httpParams, 3000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(my_httpParams, 15000);

        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
        ThreadSafeClientConnManager multiThreadedConnectionManager = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(my_httpParams, registry);

        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(multiThreadedConnectionManager, my_httpParams);

        return httpclient;
}
```

.

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";

DefaultHttpClient httpclient = createHttpClient();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

try {
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
    mStatusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

    if (mStatusCode == 200){
        content = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    }

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalStateException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When 15 seconds have passed and not all data has been received, an exception will be thrown, right? But on which method? I thought it to be the `.execute(httpget)` method but that one only tells me it throws `ClientProtocolException` and `IOException`. Could anyone help me clearifying this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It does throw an exception on `execute()`. The parent of `SocketTimeoutException` is an `IOException`. A catch block handling `IOException` will be able to catch both.

Try executing this code.

```
HttpParams my_httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(my_httpParams, 3000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(my_httpParams, 1);
DefaultHttpClient defaultHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(my_httpParams);
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://google.com");
defaultHttpClient.execute(httpGet);
```

It results in this exception.

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    ...
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:784)
```

You can always choose to selectively process the exception by catching it and handling `IOException` later.

```
try
{
    // Your code
}
catch (SocketTimeoutException e)
{
    // handle timeouts
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    // handle other IO exceptions
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Apache docs at http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d5e249, it notes that connection timeout exceptions are IOException subclasses.

To be more specific, I believe they'll either [ConnectTimeoutExceptions](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/ConnectTimeoutException.html) if the connection can't be set up within your configured connection timeout, or [SocketTimeoutExceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/SocketTimeoutException.html), if it's set up but no data is received for your configured SO timeout.